# WooCommerce coupon calculate from regular price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need functionality for "friend" customers, who can get products with better price. User role based solution is not what I'm looking for and customer wants it to work with coupons. They give coupon code to their customers and they get for example 8€ off from REGULAR price on certain products. The problem is, by default WooCommerce coupons calculate it from smallest price. If sale price is set, then this calculation is wrong and the customer gets it too cheap. Basically, I want coupon to give certain products fixed "friend" price.

I've been googling around and can't find a ready solution for it. Any suggestions how to solve this problem are welcome.

I have checked multiple plugins, but none of them has filled my requirements.

Comment: It calculates the discount from the product price. Pricing on woocommerce is handled by three price fields on the product. The regular_price, the sale_price and the price. If the product is on sale the price will = the sale price, if not on sale it equals the regular price. As you stated coupons by default are based on what the price is. You will have to achieve this with a function or custom plugin. Do you have access to modify the functions file or do you require a plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Add to functions.php. Based off of this code https://brilliantinfo.net/apply-coupon-discount-on-regular-price-in-woocommerce/

Modified for coupon type of fixed_product. If you need this to only work for a specific coupon then I can modify for that. (As it stands this will apply to any fixed_product coupons that are used)

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adjust_cart_coupon', 10, 1);
    function adjust_cart_coupon( $cart_object) {
      global $woocommerce;

      if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ){
        return;
      }

      $coupon = False;

      if ($coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons()  == False ) {
          $coupon = False;
      } else {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() as $code ) {
          $coupons1 = new WC_Coupon( $code );
          if ($coupons1->type == 'fixed_product'){
            $coupon = True;
          }
        }
      }

      if ($coupon == True){
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
          $price = $cart_item['data']->regular_price;
          //sets cart item to use regular price and not sale price
          $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Discount Rules for WooCommerce](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-discount-rules/) plugin might fit your requirements.

With it you can apply a coupon, or any discount rule, to specific customers.

Also there is a setting to **Apply discount based on** Sale price or Regular price.